# bittorrent packets make server slow

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, torrent

Server(A) ip is 192.168.0.5 and 192.168.0.6 is ip of another server(B). uTorrent is installed at Server A, and it is not executed. uTorrent is not installed at Server B. When i look packet flow, however, there are very large bittorrent packets sent by server B. Since these packet are too big, there are many PDUs assembled. Why does server B send bittorrent packet despite it is not installed?

How can i solve this problem?

Captured packets are followed:

http://kinimage.naver.net/20141024_290/1414161623305lDgKd_JPEG/%C4%B8%C3%B3.JPG?type=w620